# Bluetooth Low Energy Profile/Service Selection

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, microcontroller

My requirement is as follows:

I need to send Proximity Sensor (Reed Switches/Magnetic Sensor) reading (On/Off) from two Input Pins to a central PC.

I need to use coin cell. So basically the app should be in sleep mode and once there is any interrupt on any of these two pins it should wake up to send its state to the central PC.

I have DA18450 chip and development board (murata ZY type) with me.

[Dialog Semiconductor 18450](http://support.dialog-semiconductor.com/connectivity/product/da14580)

[Murata Bluetooth Smart Development Board](http://wireless.murata.com/eng/products/rf-modules-1/bluetooth/type-zy.html)

I am a beginner to bluetooth technology and started reading about it just a week back.

Could someone guide me about the most apt Profile/Service suitable for my application?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the device to actually sleep then it'd probably be best for it to just transmit data via advertising packets when the device awakens.  Otherwise you have to maintain a connection which requires staying awake at some level.  However, advertising packets are broadcast and the device can't know if anything received those packets (you could have it broadcast several times for a fixed period of time or have it constantly broadcast while the proximity alert is valid).  Also, on the receiving end, with no connection there's no way of knowing the transmitting device is even there when nothing is being transmitted.

The advertising packets have a section for limited information and that's where you'd transmit data if you don't want to establish a connection.

Comment: Can't I have advertising packet which when received by the central computer - central would initiate a connection to send the response that 'it has received the data'. Once the sensor device gets acknowledgement that it's data was received by the Cental, sensor device can disconnect and go to sleep again.

Comment: Advertise, connect, acknowledge, then disconnect...  Yeah, you could do that.